# Phalcon DevTools & Phalcon Compose usage issue

Tags: phalcon

I've followed [this tutorial](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/environments-docker) and this is how my project's directory looks like now:

[image]

Then, I installed Phalcon Developer Tools as described [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/devtools-usage), but I got stuck when generating a new project skeleton because it starts with creating a completely new directory making all the things Composer (for PHP) had installed useless!

On the other hand, the project as it is now have no routers and other useful things that are present in DevTools' skeleton, so the question is how do I merge them? Thanks.

Comment: To put them to the applications directory?

Comment: Do you mean all the new folder's contents?